# Python gradual typing

Tags: python, python-typing, gradual-typing

As far as I know, Python is a gradual typing language. And all unannotated variables are of type `Any` which is a supertype and subtype of any type. Why then is the following code rejected by the static type checker?

```
def doubles(x: str) -> str:
     return x + x


y = True
doubles(y)
```

I understand that the program is obviously incorrect, but how did the type checker guess? Shouldn't the following happen:

1. `y` is not annotated, therefore it is of type Any
2. cast `Any` to `str`
3. accept the program

The expected behavior occurs only if you explicitly specify the `Any` type. I would assume that without explicitly specifying `Any`, `y` would be assigned the type of the right expression, that is, `bool`, but then we would not be able to change the value of `y` to `123` type `int`, which is not true

Comment: Talking about "obvious" things: `y` is obviously not a `str`, at least to me and the type checker.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect.  Unannotated variables are not Any.  In many cases, the linter assumes a variable's type based on its first assignment.  Here, the linter assumes that y is a boolean and correctly surmises that your program is wrong.

Comment: "which is a supertype and subtype of any type" -- it's just a supertype, not a subtype.

Comment: @Barmar, i think you you are confusing Any with Object from Java. If any not subtype, then the following code will not compile, because Any is not Dog

class Animal:

    def speak(self):

        pass


class Cat(Animal):
    def speak(self):
        print("Meow")


class Dog(Animal):
    def seat(self):
        print("sitting")

    def speak(self):
        print("Woof")


def make_speak(animal):
    animal.speak()


def make_seat(dog: Dog):
    dog.seat()


x: typing.Any = Dog()

y: Dog = Dog()

make_seat(x)

make_seat(y)

Comment: It's not quite accurate to say that `Any` is a super- and sub-type of all types. See PEP-483, but in short gradual typing operates with an is-consistent-with relationship. `A` is consistent with `B` if `A` is a subtype of `B`, but also if `A` is `Any` or if `B` is `Any`.

Comment: Unannotated *function parameters* are equivalent to parameters hinted with `Any`, and a function with no defined return type is assumed to return `Any`. Other unannotated names will have type inference applied; with `y = True`, the type of `y` is inferred to be `bool`, not `Any`.

Comment: If `y` were *explicitly* hinted as `Any`, or the `x` parameter were left unhinted, then `y = True; doubles(y)` would type-check. (Either `y` would be consistent with any typed parameter, or any value would be consistent with an untyped parameter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static type checking system will also "look into" actually assigned values in the source code. And will, in fact, adopt the type of assigned values to un-annotated variables.

In your example, it "sees" just as we can do, `y` contains a  `bool`. And even if `y` would be annotated as being `bool | str`, it would see the *actual* contained value in this case is a bool. (But it actually complains about the broader type).

Moreover, it won't allow simply "more broad" values to fit into narrower annotated calls: even if you do annotate `y` as "any", fetch its value at runtime from somewhere the static typing system can't "see", it will could warn you with such a call: `doubles` requires a `str` parameter (but it actually allows it, at least mypy).